# Comparator Classes Usage

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, compare, comparator

I am trying to get this program to compile and have been stuck at this point for multiple hours now. I am trying to sort ArrayLists which contain Rectangles. I am trying to sort these rectangles by ascending widths, descending widths, and by height when the widths are the same. I have a class containing the main method and the ArrayLists' contents, and also a DescendingComparator class and an AscendingComparator class but cannot get them to run inside the main method. Here is my code. Any advice is helpful, thanks.

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SortingHomework10 extends Rectangle {
    public static void main(String[] args){




//set up first array list with rectangles of differing widths
ArrayList<Rectangle> first = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();       
Rectangle rectangleOne = new Rectangle(2,6);
Rectangle rectangleTwo = new Rectangle(4,4);
Rectangle rectangleThree = new Rectangle(2,5);

first.add(rectangleOne);
first.add(rectangleTwo);
first.add(rectangleThree);


//set up second array list with rectangles that have same width
ArrayList<Rectangle> second = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
Rectangle rectangleFour = new Rectangle(2,5);
Rectangle rectangleFive = new Rectangle(2,4);
Rectangle rectangleSix = new Rectangle(2,3);
Rectangle rectangleSeven = new Rectangle(1,3);

second.add(rectangleFour);
second.add(rectangleFive);
second.add(rectangleSix);
second.add(rectangleSeven);

System.out.println("Before sorting.");
System.out.println(first);
System.out.println("");

//Sorting in ascending width
Collections.sort(first, new AscendingComparator());
System.out.println("In ascending order by width.");
for(int j=0; j <first.size(); j++){

System.out.println(first.get(j));
}

System.out.println("");

System.out.println("In descending order by width.");
//Sorting in descending width
//for(int i = first.size() - 1; i >=0; i--){
    //System.out.println(first.get(i));
Collections.sort(first, new DescendingComparator());
}
}


//////////AscendingComparator Class code
public class AscendingComparator implements Comparator<Rectangle> {


    @Override
    public int compare(Rectangle o1, Rectangle o2) {
        if(o1.getWidth() < o2.getWidth()){
            return -1;
        }
        if(o1.getWidth() > o2.getWidth()){
            return 1;
        }
        else return 0;
    }

}

//////////////DescendingComparator Class code
public class DescendingComparator implements Comparator<Rectangle> {


    @Override
    public int compare(Rectangle o1, Rectangle o2) {
       if(o1.getWidth() > o2.getWidth()){
           return -1;
       }
       if(o1.getWidth() < o2.getWidth()){
           return 1;
       }
       else return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is happening then?

Comment: If all that code is in one class it won't compile. You are only allowed one public top-level class per Java file.

Comment: It is not, the AscendingComparator and DescendingComparator are separate classes on their own. It compiles up until the DescendingComparator class. Am I using them incorrectly in the main method?

Comment: So what are the actual errors?

Comment: I was finally able to figure it out. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're sorting the first collection twice and not doing anything with the second after you built it up.

Comment: You can disregard the second ArrayList, that is there for the by height sorting which I have not coded yet. I am sorting the first twice, first I am sorting and displaying it in ascending, then descending.